# Can I post feedback about the insights of development for accessibility?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, accessibility

I should like to offer some small insights into the development of an accessible application from the possibly rather rare perspective of a severely visually impaired user developing for my own use.

Would this be the correct site in which to do so, and, indeed, is it of any interest?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if Stack Overflow is the correct site to ask questions about developing accessible applications?

Comment: If you mean where to post feedback about the accessibility of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network of sites, then yes, this site (Meta), is the right place to post such feedback.

Comment: Assuming that you do want to offer your feedback, then as a developer here at Stack Exchange, working on the Stack Overflow codebase, I am certainly very interested in any such feedback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That dup is waaaay too broad.

Comment: No, while working as a  severely visually impaired (amateur) programmer on an application for myself, I learned a considerable amount about my own needs and the needs of other visually impaired users  and came across a number of issues not discussed in most of the accessibility guidelines I looked at.  These insights could possibly be of benefit to professional developers faced with accessibility issues..

Comment: @rene: Yet it applies to this question too; developing for the visually impaired is software development within certain constraints, but certainly still software development. You'd have UX issues (for which there is a dedicated site), or issues with specific hardware and their software frameworks (would be OT on Stack Overflow), or you'd have issues with how to set up end-user testing (perhaps OT on Programmers). What aspects of development for the visually impaired is *unique* in that it deserves a separate question here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't see it as much of a "what site do I post this on" issue though. More of a "can I share my experiences" deal. Which goes more into suitability for the Q&A format than that it's a site-recommendation issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the aspect of development by the visually impaired?

Comment: @Bart: Fair enough; vote retracted.

Comment: Incidentally, whoever changed the original title of my post may well have caused some confusion. The question was never about feedback on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you might have noticed, the sites within this network are Q&A's (which is different from a forum by the way). Questions and answers are what we do. And that is a somewhat limited format.

It seems you want to provide general advice and insights. While that might be of great value to others, it sounds like something that would be more suitable for a blog. The network itself doesn't really make such posts a great fit.

The only way around this would be to come up with an actual question to answer. Something that is practical and on-topic for the site. But that's a tricky thing to do, because the question should be practical and good enough for the site. That you're the one answering it doesn't matter. And regarding the subject matter, Stack Overflow might not be the proper site for it.

So all in all I don't think Stack Overflow is suitable. Other sites might be more welcoming, but even then it's difficult at best, given the Q&A format.

Comment: OK. Just thought I may be able to pay back in a small way for all the help. I was using "forum" incidentally in its (dare I say) "proper" meaning :(

Comment: @BlindFury I can see how such practical feedback could be of great value to developers everywhere, it's just the format that's going to limit you unfortunately. I saw Martijn mention the UX site. Perhaps you could have a look at their questions and see if you could attempt a self-answer there. But I don't participate over there, so I can't make any statement on suitability for their site. But if anything, blog it. Create a nice write-up and share it with the world.

Comment: I haven't checked in lately, but UX was talking about a blog at one point and *that* might be a good place to share such material.  Worth looking on their meta for blog-related posts, at least.  (I recognize that there's more to accessibility than UX.)  Questions about accessibility are on-topic on UX, so if you can formulate some of these as Q&A try there.